# Turning a string into a formatted paragraph in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Edit: Since people seem a little confused, I will try to clarify.

Essentially, the string you take is a variable character length and can be any number of lines.

The hitch is the string has to not cutoff a word. So, as another example, the string:

'The jumping fox' is divided into 2 separate lines.
The middle character is 'u', so the two lines would be:
Line 1: 'The jumping'
Line 2: 'Fox'
to prevent the word being cutoff. So that is the two restrictions.

So, I got this question:

Given a single-line text String and a maximum line value, write the function that formats the input text , i.e: Divide the text evenly based on character, and return a new line for each section of the string. But do not cut off a line -- ie, if you have 1000 character, and 2 lines, you can increase the size of the first line to capture the end of the last word in the middle of the 500th character.

I am bashing my head trying to solve it in JavaScript. Any tips? It's easy enough to just return the lines without this whitespace formatting, but I am totally lost.

```
function formatString(string, numlines) {
  var length = string.length;
  console.log(length);
  var words = string.split(' ');
  var paraLength = parseInt(string.length/numlines);
  console.log(paraLength)

  var paragraph = [];  
  for(var i=0; i<length;) {
    // console.log('i is: ', i);
    console.log('start of string is: ', string.charAt(i));
    console.log('end of string is: ', string.charAt(i+paraLength+1));
    console.log('if true? ', string.indexOf(i) )
    if (string.charAt(i+paraLength) == ' ') {
      var thing = string.substr(i,i+paraLength);
      console.log('if thing is: ', thing);
      i+=paraLength;
      console.log('if i is: ', i);
      paragraph.push(thing);
    } else {
      var thing = string.substr(i,i+paraLength);
      console.log('else thing is: ', thing);
      console.log('blah is: ',i+paraLength+1 >= length);
      while (string.charAt(i+paraLength) != ' ' && i+paraLength < length) {
        thing.concat(string.charAt(i+paraLength+1));
        thing.concat('hi')
        console.log('else thing is: ', thing);
        i+=1;
        console.log('i is: ', i);
      }
      paragraph.push(thing);
      i+= paraLength;
    }
  }

  return paragraph.map(function(d) {
    console.log('d is: ', d);
    return d;
  }).join('')

}
console.log(formatString('hello world blah blah blah', 2));
```

Comment: You need the power of [`string.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice).

Comment: Is there a hard limit on the length of any particular line so long as there are at most `n` lines?

Comment: No hard limit. It just can just vary due to what is contained in the string

Comment: this is still vague to me, I was playing around and I think I have it, what exactly would be the log for `'hello world blah blah blah', 2` ?

Comment: I think it should be with that string... Line 1: hello world blah, line 2: blah blah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding you're question, this might help:

```
function formatString(string, numlines) {
    var length = string.length;
    var paraLength = Math.round((string.length)/numlines);
    var paragraphs = [];
    for (var i=0; i<numlines; i++) {
        var marker = paraLength;
        //if the marker is right after a space, move marker back one character
        if (string.charAt(marker-1) == " ") {
            marker--; 
        }
        //move marker to end of a word if it's in the middle
        while(string.charAt(marker) != " " && string.charAt(marker) != "") {
            marker++;
        }
        var nextPara = string.substring(0, marker)
        paragraphs.push(nextPara)
        string = string.substring((nextPara.length+1),string.length)
    }
    return paragraphs
}
```

This returns an array that contains the individual paragraphs.

```
formatString("The jumping fox", 2) // => ["The jumping", "fox"]
```

Answer (score 2):

The proposed algorithm "you can increase the size of the first line to capture the end of the last word in the middle of the 500th character" has a fatal flaw: if your last word is longer than `length(sentence)/num_lines` and so you skip to 'the next word', you print out too many words in that line and end up with too little words – probably none at all – in the last line.

This can be solved by not considering a string as a *sequence of characters* (where you need to inspect each character to see if it is a space) but rather as a *sequence of words*. Then, the algorithm is that on each line `num_words/num_lines` must appear. Use `Math.ceil` to round up, so you are sure that on every line at least one word appears.

With that, you can create a basic test case to split up a list of words exactly in 2. The splitting itself could be done using the `split` function, but I prefer a regex `match`, so all spaces are preserved. `match` returns an array of matches, each of which are a single word plus its following whitespace. Since it's an array, you can divide its length by the number of lines, round up if it's a fraction (`Math.ceil`), then print out those words.

Next? Well, after that step you end up with a not-yet processed remainder of your original string and with a number of lines remaining. So you can call **this same function again** with the truncated string and one less number of lines. You are done when the number of lines is `1` (then the entire remaining string can be printed) and/or the number of spaces is `0` (not tested for here; I suppose you could first see if you have at least as many spaces-minus-1 as you have lines, and if not, issue an error).

```
console.log(formatString('hello world blah blah blah', 2));

function formatString (string, numLines)
{
    var wordlist, trim_at, result;
    if (numLines < 2)
        return string;

    wordlist = string.match(/\S+\s*/g);
    trim_at = Math.ceil(wordlist.length/numLines);

    result = '';
    while (trim_at--)
        result += wordlist.shift();
    result += '\n';
    result += formatString (wordlist.join(''), numLines-1);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: But by splitting it up by words something like `"superlongword a a a a a a"` gets split up into the lines `"superlongword a a a"` and `"a a a"` instead of `"superlongword" ` and `"a a a a a a"`

Comment: I get what you're going for -- essentially, as numlines gets large and the string gets large, the chance the last lines will be truncated is pretty high. 

I imagine the secret is probably going backwards and forward to the NEAREST whitespace, not the whitespace the end like I think you were getting at.